# Ajax set content from POST call

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, json, post

I need to do this call and set the page content ( complete document ) from the response I got. Something is wrong with this line : 
$(document.documentElement).innerHTML = response.responseText;
What could be ?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/sakila",
    data: userAsJson,
    success: function(response){
        $(document.documentElement).innerHTML = response.responseText;
        return response;
    }
});
```

Comment: `dataType : "json"` i think you are missing this. Also if you could tell us your json structure. `console.log(response);` what is it giving you. try putting in success method and look into the browser console.

Answer (score 1):

First off, `return response` can't be returned like that. You may call a function passing a value into that function with resposne. AJAX is Asynchronous (Asynchronous JavaScript and XML), so returning won't help you there. Also use `.html()` instead of Native DOM methods, unless you know what you're doing.

You probably don't want to be using [document.documentElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.documentElement), as that returns the root element of the document. `<html>` . Use a HTML element other than that and select it via jQuery.

```
function successCallback() {
  $(document.documentElement).html(this.responseText);
}
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/sakila",
    data: userAsJson,
    success: function(response){
        // either do everything in here, or pass the object to a function not both
        $(document.documentElement).html(response.responseText);
        // OR
        successCallback.call(response);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for the jQuery way:

```
$(document.documentElement).innerHTML(response.responseText);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your want to do this with **Jquery**:

```
$("#yourcontainer").html(response.responseText);
```

and with **Javascript**:

```
document.getElementById("#yourcontainer").innerHtml = response.responseText;
```

<kbd>[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakmanwal/bEtRc/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Try this (If `response` is a json object) -

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/sakila",
    data: userAsJson,
    success: function(response){
        $(document.documentElement).innerHTML = JSON.stringify(response); //may be response is a json object, so this might help
        //return response; //not needed and does not work either
    }
});
```